# JLayeredPane returning null on getParent()

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

My situation: I have a class MainScreen that extends JFrame (it really is just a JFrame with a main method to start the application) on which I added a class GameManager that extends JLayeredPane, that I'm using to display something.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainScreen ms = new MainScreen();
}

public MainScreen() {
    this.initScreen();
    this.gm = new GameManager();
    this.add(gm, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now, what I want to do is, from the GameManager class I want to add a JButton to the main JFrame. I thought it would be easy, just do:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
this.getParent().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

but getParent() is returning null, so obviously it doesn't work. I don't know why though, I did something similar before (with a JComponent and a JPanel though), and I thought that every JComponent when added to a container would have the container as its parent. What did I miss?

Comment: Is your GameManager actually added to JFrame before you call getParent()?

Comment: Where does `this.getParent().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` exist in `GameManager.java`? within constructor?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it, that was a dumb error. But now getParent() is returning a JPanel and not a JFrame, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following statement:

`this.getParent().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

exists within constructor of `GameManager.java`, then `getParent() is returning null` is correct. It is because the object of `GameManager` is added to `MainScreen` after the call to `this.getParent().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`.

As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

> Each top-level container has a content pane that, generally speaking,
>   contains (directly or indirectly) the visible components in that
>   top-level container's GUI.

In case of `JFrame` the default content pane is a `JPanel`. So when you made a call to `this.add(gm, BorderLayout.CENTER);`, you actually added the instance of `GameManager` to the default content pane of `JFrame` i.e. `a JPanel`. That is why `GameManager.getParent()` is a `JPanel`. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it, that was a dumb error. (It's not in the constructor but it's in a method called by it, that's why I didn't notice). But now getParent() is returning a JPanel and not a JFrame, how so?

Comment: I haven't invoked setContentPane at all, I just set title, size and default close operation.